# Why can't I properly create a table with a foreign key?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-migrations

I want to create 2 tables:

1. A table called `roles`
2. And a table called `users`

In `users` I want to have a column called `role_id` and it should be a reference to `roles` table.

This is how `roles` table should look like:

[image: Roles table]

So here is a migration for `user` table:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();

    $table->bigInteger('role_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('role_id')->references('role_id')->on('roles');

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

And here is a migration for `roles` talbe:

```
Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
});
```

The error I get when I run `php artisan migrate`

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `my_db`.`users` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint `users_role_id_foreign` foreign key (`role_id`) references `roles` (`role_id`))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change references('role_id') in references('id') which means that references in column 'id' in roles table:

```
$table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
```

Also you should create first roles table and after that users table.
Just change the dates on database/migrations like this (example):

> 2020_09_11_150331_create_roles_table.php
> 2020_09_12_000000_create_users_table.php

run:

```
php artisan migrate
```

This way first will be created the roles table and then users table which will handle a foreign key which references 'id' column in roles table.

Comment: Thank you very much. For those who are still struggling with the problem I would recommend to check the size of the foreign key and the key. They should be the same

Answer (score 3):

There is an definition problem make it like `$table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');`

or you need to make primary key of roles table as `role_id` i guess this will resolve what you are looking for